# Is Bingo Games Solved?

Tags: combinatorics, game-theory

So we have numbers 5 rows by 5 columns. Different players have the same table. The numbers on each cell of the tables are different. Different players choose which numbers will be marked.

We select a number. Every number that we select also shows up on opponent screen.

The goal is to make lines, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally. Those who make 5 lines first win.

My strategy is to simply compute "values" in each cells. The value is the number of all other cells that form a line. To provide more incentive to complete cells, lines with many mark already get chosen first.

We can try to complete a line or pick spots with more possible line closing. My algorith is to always pick lines that is the closest to compete. So far, my program can defeat me most of the time.

Is this optimum strategy that can't be defeated?

Comment: Homer Simpson has an optimum strategy, he cheats! :-)

Comment: You should challenge my algorithm. Coming to android soon.

Comment: We make a line by marking every cell in the line.